# Display json as Error nicely

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I am doing validation server side, If fails I am passing back json data with the errors.

I'm not worried about displaying the errors on page but happy with just a simple alert().

How can I display the errors nicely while using a $each function with jquery.

Here is some json data.

```
{"error":["The Firstname field is required.","The Lastname field is required.","The Address 1 field is required.","The City field is required.","The Zipcode field is required.","The Receive Mailing List field is required."]}
```

Displaying messy would be like

```
$.each(msg.error, function(k, v) {
 alert(v);   
});
```

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an alert but not individually for each message, you can just use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array here, like this:

```
alert(msg.error.join('\n'));
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/59yHd/), you'll get one alert with a message on each line, like this:

> The Firstname field is required.
>   The Lastname field is required.
>   The Address 1 field is required.
>   The City field is required.
>   The Zipcode field is required.
>   The Receive Mailing List field is required.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do that. Nothing is more annoying than a bunch of alert messages. If you want to display all the errors then combine all the errors into one string and display them with one alert.

Comment: I don't think the op wants an alert message for each error. All the errors listed in one alert box (as Nick has done above) would not be that bad (to a limit). The validation summary control allows you to do this as well (I mention this as an example, not a suggestion).

Comment: "happy with just a simple alert()."

Comment: Since you're quoting exactly, "a" isn't plural :)